# How a subfolder of domain having different IP

Tags: domain, directory, magento

We have multiple ecommerce platforms. Say, Magento and Shopware. Magento and Shopware are hosted in different servers. We want to migrate all Magento stores to Shopware.

The domain name of Magento platform is aaa.com [IP Address: 111.111.111.111] and Shopware platform is bbb.com[IP Address: 222.222.222.222].  We want aaa.com/en to be hosted on Shopware platform [IP Address 222.222.222.222]. And all other substores of magento will be still using Magento. We know subdomain of domain can have different IP [en.aaa.com].

We want the subfolder of a domain to be hosted in different server. How to achieve this?

[Migrating one substore from one server to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV4MQ.jpg)

Comment: What web server software are you running? Actual process depends on `apache` vs `nginx` vs whatever else...   but basically, you tell the server to recognize the name `en.aaa.com` to have a specific Document Root for it.

Comment: Both ecommerce platforms are using Apache webserver. We have multiple stores in one domain. for eg: aaa.com/en , aaa.com/es , aaa.com/it , aaa.com/pt . And this domains are using magento. As the process of migration, we want to migrate only aaa.com/en to another server with another ip address. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

On the aaa.com , you need to setup a reverse proxy for all URL in aaa.com/en .

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use the CNAME record, as well as a different document root, as @ivanivan pointed out in the comment.

See this link for a  [quick example of how CNAME can help you](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46947/cname-does-a-cname-change-the-url-that-the-browser-displays)